# Prevent iOS app from deep sleeping efficiently

Tags: ios

I'm building an alarm clock that allows the user to play a continuous sound at a specific fire date while the app is in the foreground and the screen is locked.

https://github.com/mruegenberg/MMPDeepSleepPreventer is the only solution I've found to prevent my app from exiting after 10 minutes. However, this approach is causing significant battery drain.

Are there any other approaches to this problem without draining the battery significantly? I know it is possible because there are other alarm clocks out there that do this without killing the battery and without jailbreak.

Comment: That component should be banned :D ... that really is a nasty way of cheating.

Comment: Perhaps... but some apps are enhanced by the ability to run in the background. It's a limitation that Apple should really work on

Comment: I am also pretty sure that apps using that component as is, will be rejected from sales via iTunes. Apple lately became **VERY** specific on the usage of `UIBackgroundModes`. When using the audio setting, you  will have to play audible audio content.

Comment: Download Alarm Clock HD - Free, set an alarm for 15 minutes in the future. Lock the screen and leave the app running in the foreground. It will play an alarm sound in addition to a local notification. Many alarm clock apps do this and I believe they pass the iTunes authentication process because they do require sounds to be played.

What do you have against this method? Is there a better solution that you are aware of?

Comment: That exactly is the point, audible content.